# How can I updated the url without reloading the page?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following code that lets me update the url without reloading the page:

```
function SomeCtrl($scope, $http, $rootScope, $stateParams, $location) {
    var scope = $rootScope;
    scope.doSomething = function(){
       $location.path('updated/url').notify(false);
    }
}

<div ng-click="doSomething()">Click Here</div>
```

The problem that I'm having is that I get the following message in the console: "TypeError: undefined is not a function". But, the url IS updated and the page doesn't reload, which is what I want. Should I just ignore the error message in the console?

Comment: I may be being dumb here.. it is the end of the day, but angular does html5 pushstate by default... that is, changing the url without reloading the page. For your undefined error, where is it coming from? Do you click the button and get the error? You probably don't want to just leave that.

Comment: Are you chaining the notify() on the path call because you expect a promise to be returned?  Because path returns the path and not a promise (and thus, natively doesn't have a notify property)

Comment: Yes, when I click the button the url is updated as it should. Basically everything seems to work fine, except that I get the warning in the console. I'm chaining notify() on the path because it is what prevents the url from reloading (at least that's how I understand it).

Comment: There was a PR for a .notify() on $location but it appears it was rejected (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2398).